# I have just started learning Python. Whats wrong with this code?

Tags: python, python-3.3

```
import random
print("Let's play the Random Number Game")
guess=random.randint(1,15)
print("\n I've choosed a random Number from 1 to 15", "Try guessing the number")
def strt( ):
userguess=input("\n Enter the number")
if userguess==guess :
    print("wow! you've guessed the correct number in" ,"time")
else:
    if userguess>guess:
        print("Guess a smaller number")
            strt( )
    else : print("Guess a Larger number")
            strt( )
strt()
input("Hit Enter to Exit")
```

I have just started learning Python. Whats wrong with this code?

Comment: You tell us, what error did it throw?

Comment: Your indentation is off

Comment: [indentation is important.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation)

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the lack of **Proper Indentation** your program also contained a minor bug.

`input()` returns a `str` in Python and you cannot compare strings with ints in Python without doing some kind of conversion. e.g:

```
userguess = int(input("Guess: "))
```

Without this type conversion a `TypeError` is thrown like this:

```
>>> "foo" > 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

A correct version of your program with proper indentation and the above bug fixed:

```
import random


print("Let's play the Random Number Game")
guess = random.randint(1, 15)
print("\n I've choosed a random Number from 1 to 15", "Try guessing the number")


def strt():
    userguess = int(input("\n Enter the number"))
    if userguess == guess:
        print("wow! you've guessed the correct number in", "time")
    else:
        if userguess > guess:
            print("Guess a smaller number")
            strt()
        else:
            print("Guess a Larger number")
            strt()


strt()
input("Hit Enter to Exit")
```

Comment: Yay, two answers at the exact same second :)

Comment: Oh well :) I'm just trying to relax after work and see if I can't build up my reputation a wee bit :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code lacks proper indentation.

Python code uses indentation instead of other syntaxes for code blocks, like pairs of `begin` and `end` as found in Pascal, or `{` and `}` as found in C++, so correct indentation is crucial for the Python compiler in order to do its job.

Answer (score 0):

OK, assuming you've fixed the indentation, there's another problem: You're comparing the integer `guess` with a string `userguess`. Therefore, the equality check will always fail, and the comparison check will throw a `TypeError`:

```
>>> "1" == 1
False
>>> "1" > 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

You need to call `int()` on your user's input in order to make the variables comparable.